# Is it a good idea to close a class-level database connection on a page/control's Unload event?

Tags: asp.net, database, connection

In my page codebehind, I have a class-level, lazy-loaded connection property that instantiates and opens when it is referenced.  I never close the connection after it is used.  Instead, I close it during the page's unload event.  This eliminates the extra code needed to close it off every time I am done with it.  So far, it appears to work, but I am interested in hearing about any possible negative implications of doing it this way.

Here's what it looks like:

```
Dim _DbConnection As MyConnection
Private ReadOnly Property DbConnection As MyConnection
    Get
        If _DbConnection Is Nothing Then _DbConnection = GetNewConnection()
        Return _DbConnection
    End Get
End Property

Private Sub Page_Unload(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Unload
    CloseConnection(DbConnectionConnection)
End Sub
```

**Edit:** I appreciate the answers advising it is a bad idea, but *what are the negative implications* of doing it the way I am?  If it's not a good idea, there has to be a legitimate reason as to why.

Answer (score 1):

"I never close the connection after it is used" this is horrible idea.  you can use Using blocks to ensure proper dispoing of resoruces.

this what i suggest.

```
 using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strconString))
   {
     // do some logic 
    }
```

Comment: By that, I meant I never close it off immediately after I am finished using it (typically within the same block or method).  Instead, it always gets closed off during the page's unload event.  The only foreseeable issue is that it remains open a few split seconds longer when closed during the unload event rather than immediately after, but it always gets closed off in the end.  Also, I could also call the connections's .Dispose method on the Unload event, could I not?

Comment: @oscilatingcretin
You should use [Using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for the issue you mentioned. Object will be disposed as soon as it goes out of scope.

Comment: I agree about the using statement, but what I am really interested in are the negative implications of closing it the way I am on the Unload event.  It seems legit so long as the connection is ultimately being closed every single time.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Ravi that this is a bad idea. A better practice is to always close your db connection as soon as you finish each query, and you should use connection pooling to improve performance.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

I think it is a bad idea because it makes for less obvious code, which can lead to bugs later. If another developer takes a look at the code, it will not be obvious to him how the connection is being closed, and as a result he may make modifications that introduce bugs. You want your code to be readable and obvious. Using page life cycle tricks to save a couple milliseconds is just going to lead to problems down the road.

Comment: Okay, let's assume it's well documented as to how I am handling the connection.  What I am looking for here are objectively measurable impacts that this can have on the system or how it can introduce direct complications.  A developer coming in after me and writing buggy code due to his or her misunderstanding of my code is more subjective since it is contingent on the developer's ability to understand code with varying levels of documentation.

Comment: The best practice is to open and close connections as close to the actual query that is using it as possible. I think the better question is: What are the objectively measurable impacts that using the best practice can have on the system? What are you gaining by deviating from the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

As quoted from there:

> In controls, use this event to do final cleanup for specific controls,
>   such as closing control-specific database connections.
>
> For the page itself, use this event to do final cleanup work, such as
>   closing open files and database connections, or finishing up logging
>   or other request-specific tasks.

My recommendation would be to avoid the unload event. When possible do any cleanup code sooner rather than later, so use "using" if you can. In a way, it's like the choice between using a "global" variable as opposed to a local variable, the latter is preferable

Or alternative (using `System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection`)

```
string sConnString = "Server=localhost;Database=Northwind;Integrated Security=True"; 
string sSql = "SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName FROM Categories ORDER BY CategoryName"; 
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(sConnString); 
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sSql, cn); 
cn.Open(); 
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
rdr.Read();
//execute
rdr.Close();//closing reader closing connection
```